# If any values in this list exist else give me everything

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In a SQL Server proc we may pass in a string list of values. Sometimes this can be an empty string. We break this string (which is a csv string) and store each value in a temp table. Again, it can be blank and so in that case the temp table is empty.

What we're trying to do in the where clause is have it run against the temp table but if there is no data run it against everything. There is a 'trick' that I've never used before and not sure if I fully understand that others at work have used but it's not working for this query (it kills performance and the query never comes back when it should in 4 seconds otherwise).

Below is an example query and the where part is the key:

```
DECLARE @myList AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @myList = '73'

CREATE TABLE #TempList (data int)

INSERT INTO #TempList
SELECT * FROM BreakCSV(@myList,',')

DECLARE @Count int

SELECT @Count = COUNT(data) FROM #TempList sl WHERE ISNULL(sl.data,0) <> 0

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDateField BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '3/1/2015'
AND (MyIdField IN (SELECT data FROM #TempList WHERE data <> 0) OR @Count = 0)
```

That OR part with the @Count is the trick. If TempList has no records then @Count would equal 0 and 0 = 0 should cause it to pull the entire table. However, even if TempList has a record in it, the mere fact of having the OR @Count = 0 makes the query not come back. If I comment out the @Count = 0 then it comes back in 4 seconds as expected.

I'm curious if someone could explain the logic in this thought process and if there is a different way to do something like this without an IF statement and duplicating this query with just different where clauses when you want some specific values or you want them all WITHOUT having to specify them all. Also, no dynamic sql.

Comment: Did an estimate execution plan and without the OR part est # rows is 30k. With the OR est # rows is 14 million (it's a big table). So I suppose since it could be everything it takes longer even though the date filter should limit that and it will never return 14 million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example code, this would seem to be a better way to optimize. Remember - sometimes, more code *is* better.

```
DECLARE @myList AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Count int

SET @myList = '73'

CREATE TABLE #TempList (data int)

INSERT INTO #TempList
SELECT DISTINCT data 
FROM BreakCSV(@myList,',')
WHERE data != 0

SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix1 ON #tempList(data)

IF @count = 0
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyDateField BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '3/1/2015'
ELSE
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN #TempList
        ON MyIdField = data
    WHERE MyDateField BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '3/1/2015'
```

Comment: Yes, this will be our "brute force" approach if we can't figure anything out. I hate duplicating code but if we have to we have to.

Comment: @user441521 Did you create unique index on temporary table as Laughing Vergil suggests? I've tried it and query plan looks promising. Of course, you need to not insert zeros into temporary table in order for index to be unique (I know I'm stating the obvious, but I also know that silly errors - due to too many tries in too short a time - may lead to dismissing viable solution).

Comment: @user441521 Additional option is `option(recompile)` at the end of a query. This will generate query plan suited for current parameters. Since `@count = 0` is a constant, OR branch will be eliminated, leaving or removing `IN` condition as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You overengineered this.  Get rid of this:

```
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = COUNT(data) FROM #TempList sl WHERE ISNULL(sl.data,0) <> 0
```

Change this:

```
AND (MyIdField IN (SELECT data FROM #TempList WHERE data <> 0) OR @Count = 0)
```

to this:

```
AND (MyIdField IN (SELECT data FROM #TempList WHERE data <> 0) OR @myList is null)
```

This is a common approach when writing stored procedures with optional parameters.

Comment: This doesn't change the behavior of poor performance that I'm seeing. When I remove the OR @myList is null part it comes back in 4 seconds when I have 1 value in #TempList. With it in, it's going on 1 min so far as I'm testing and still going. I've waited 15 mins before I killed it in the past. So this doesn't explain why that would cause performance issues or how it works in general.

Comment: AND (MyIdField IN (SELECT data FROM #TempList WHERE data <> 0) /*OR myList is null*/) = 4 seconds AND (MyIdField IN (SELECT data FROM #TempList WHERE data <> 0) OR myList is null) = never seems to finish.

Comment: This seems to be parenthesized badly - not necessarily incorrectly, but in a way that the parser and optimizer can't handle well.. Try `AND (@myList is null OR (MyIdField IN (SELECT data FROM #TempList WHERE data <> 0)))` for the condition instead.

Comment: Didn't make a difference in run-time. The est execution plan ended up being the same as well, but I agree it's like the parser/optimizer can't figure something out.

Comment: I guess I'll say that this table is over a DB link. Not sure if that makes a difference in a special case like this.